# Fragment to Fragment transaction in Adapter Class Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

Hello I'm new in Android Developing and I'm creating a family Application in Android Studio. Whenever I want to go to another fragment in Adapter class the fragment is overlapping old fragment.

I want to go to Another fragment name SubFamilyFragment() from the adapter class.

I tried many ways from internet but I'm not getting success.

Here is my Adapter class code

````
import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.CheckBox
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.mks.Fragments.SubFamilyFragment
import com.example.mks.Models.Family
import com.example.mks.R


class FamilyRecyclerAdapter(val context: Context, val familyList: ArrayList<Family>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<FamilyRecyclerAdapter.viewHolder>() {
    class viewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val familyName : TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.familyName)
        val familyMember : TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.familyMemberCount)
        val subFamily : CheckBox = view.findViewById(R.id.chkSubFamily)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): viewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.family_recycler_single_row,parent,false)

        return viewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return familyList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: viewHolder, position: Int) {
        val number = familyList[position]
        holder.familyName.text = number.familyName
        holder.familyMember.text = number.familyMember.toString()
        holder.subFamily.text = number.subFamily.toString()

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            val activity : AppCompatActivity = it.context as AppCompatActivity

            if (number.subFamily){
//                val fragment2 = SubFamilyFragment()
//                val fragmentTransaction: FragmentTransaction = activity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
//                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment2)
//                fragmentTransaction.commit()

                val myFragment: Fragment = SubFamilyFragment()
                (it.getContext() as AppCompatActivity).supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, myFragment).addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit()
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(context,"No Sub Family",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
}```


This code is working but the fragment is overlapping.

Please tell me what to do.
````

Comment: The `R.id.nav_host_fragment` seems to imply that you're using the Navigation Architecture Component and a `NavHostFragment`. Is there a reason you're trying to do FragmentTransactions instead of [using the NavController APIs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate)?